Do C# pattern expressions short circuit like if statements do?
I have the following line of code.
if (_lazyHeightMap.IsValueCreated && _lazyHeightMap.Value is { IsEmpty: false })

I make the first check because I do not want my code to attempt to retrieve the value from a lazy object if it has not yet been created..  I know that the language guarantees that if the left side of this expression evaluates to false, then the right side part will not be evaluated.
However, Resharper suggests that I merge this code into a pattern.  When I agree, it  converts it to the following:
if (_lazyHeightMap is { IsValueCreated: true, Value.IsEmpty: false })

My concern is this: Do I get the same guarantee about the order of evaluation and short-circuting from this pattern that I do from my compound if statements?
When I read in the C# language reference under the "logical patterns" section, I find this note highlighted which seems to indicate I will not.

The order in which patterns are checked is undefined. At run time, the
right-hand nested patterns of or and and patterns can be checked
first.

Now technically what I have here is a property pattern.  But when I read under the property pattern section of the spec I find

The order in which subpatterns are matched is not specified, and a
failed match may not match all subpatterns at runtime

If I'm reading this right, it sounds like I should report this as a bug to Resharper.  Not that it produces code that doesn't do what the original code did.  But that it produces code that is not guaranteed to do what the original code did.
So am I reading it right?

Looks like it. I'd probably try to make a [mre] and look at lowered and IL codes. If the suspicion is confirmed, I'd raise the issue with ReSharper or at least disable that specific suggestion.

I can produce an example.  But even it if performs correctly in my example, that won't really answer my question.  I am not as interested in knowing, "Might it act correctly" (it might) so much as "Is it guaranteed to act correctly".  I really need a language lawyer here.  I guess I will wait a day or so and, if I do not get some definitive answer one way or the other, I'll raise it with Resharper regardless.

One example of behaving differently breaks the guarantee. So if you have a test that performs correctly then you didn't prove anything. But if it performs otherwise you have your case.

do you get the same suggestion if you had another property and not IsValueCreated - maybe ReSharper is being super smart...figuring out that in this special case it's the same (having the null check Value before accessing IsEmpty may be thing that IsValueCreated property is doing in its getter)

I think what it comes down to is that the spec allows compilers freedom, but the current compiler does seem to use left-to-right short-circuiting. You may need to open an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang or https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn to get more clarity
